# android regarding file read from sandbox

Tags: android

I have a file by name settings.xml which I copy from asset to sandbox, if the file is not present in the sandbox. This file, then, I am trying to read from the sandbox in a second activity. I am getting errors,kindly help me.

```
/* copy file from asset to sandbox if not available in sandbox */
private void copymyfiles(String filename)
{
    FileInputStream fInp;

    try 
    {
       fInp = openFileInput(filename);
       if(fInp != null)
       {
          Log.i(“ ","Setting File read is found in sandbox ");    
       }
    }  
    catch (FileNotFoundException e1) 
    {
       /* file is not there in the sandbox. so copy from asset  */
       e1.printStackTrace();
       AssetManager assetManager = this.getAssets();
       try   
       {
          InputStream in = assetManager.open(filename);
          Log.i(“ ","opened  settings xml");
          try 
          { 
             FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput(filename,MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
             OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);  
             try 
             {
                char current;
                String result = "";
                while (in.available() > 0) 
                {
                   current = (char) in.read();
                   result = result + String.valueOf(current);  
                }
                Log.v("apr 4",result);
                out.write(result);
          } 
          catch (IOException ex) 
          {
            ex.printStackTrace();
          } 

    finally 
    {
            try 
            {
                if (in != null)
                in.close();
                if (out != null)
                    out.close();
            } 
            catch (IOException ex) 
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
   } 

catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
{
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
   Log.i(“ testing","error opeing settings from sandbox");

}

 } 

 catch (IOException e) 
 {
    //  Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.i(“ ","error in getting asset manager");
 }
 }
```

After this in the new activity I am trying to read the file

```
FileInputStream fIn = null;
File file = getBaseContext().getFileStreamPath("Settings.xml");
if (file.exists()) 
{
   Log.v(" ", "File exist in sandbox");
   try 
   {
      Log.v("", "trying to read from sandbox ");
  fIn = openFileInput("Settings.xml");
   } 
   catch (FileNotFoundException e2) 
   {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  Log.v(" ", "failed to read from sandbox ? ");
  e2.printStackTrace();

  }
```

but this gives me " java.lang.NullPointerException" error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to solve the problem:

```
context = getActivity();
FileInputStream fin = context.openFileInput(FILENAME);
```

That should make it work.